# send message to loggded In user using parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have created a database on parse.com

I want to send push notification to logged in user

I have created "Installation" class.
in that class I have added two devices with device token.
and after logged in app I have added field "owner" with loginId.

After that I am trying to send push notification to logged in used from my device but my code not working

here is code of send button

```
- (IBAction)WRMethodBtnSendMsg:(id)sender {


// Send a notification to all devices subscribed to the "Giants" channel.

  PFQuery *tmpQuery = [PFInstallation query];
  [tmpQuery whereKey:@"owner" containsString:[self.sdPFObject objectId]];

  PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
  [push setQuery:tmpQuery];
  [push setMessage:self.wrTxtMsg.text];
  [push sendPushInBackground];
 }
```

but push notification doesn't send

Appreciate for help

Comment: Have you create the push certificates and uploaded them to Parse.com? Have you prompted to user to receive push notifications?

Comment: @picciano I have checked push notification for all devices using channel property and it works well

Answer (score 0):

I'd use channels. Have every user subscribe to a "user channel", something along the line of `user_*user_id_here*`. Then, when you want to send a push notification to the user with ID 123456, simply send it to the `user_123456` channel.